# Changing repository layout in Nexus

Tags: maven, jenkins, nexus

I am deploying Maven artifacts built using Maven to Nexus and am using the following Maven command in Jenkins to do the Nexus deploy.

```
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy-file

file=abc.ear
groupId=myGroup
artifactId=ModuleA
version=1.0
url=${NEXUS_URL}/dev-repository
repositoryId=dev-repository
```

I am deploying multiple modules and am calling the above command thrice for three modules. The resulting repo structure in Nexus looks like this -

```
myGroup
|
-ModuleA
 |
 -1.0
  |
  -abc.ear
-ModuleB
 |
 -1.0
  |
  -abc.ear
-ModuleC
 |
 -1.0
  |
  -abc.ear
```

So far, so good. However, I would prefer to have a structure which is like -

```
myGroup
|
-1.0
 |
 -ModuleA
  -abc.ear
 -ModuleB
  -abc.ear
 -ModuleC
  -abc.ear
```

How can I achieve this? I see the documentation of the maven-deploy-plugin referring to 'repositoryLayout'. How can I possibly use it to get this particular folder structure?

Comment: First if you are manually doing deploy-file it sounds like you doing something wrong. Cause usually via a maven build you simply do: `mvn deploy` that's it...Apart from that if you are working with EAR you usually have multi module build which contains the different parts like EJB, JAR or multiple EAR's if you like within a single tree which can be deployed also via `mvn deploy` ....

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. This is a valid point, but there are reasons why we are not using a simple 'maven deploy'. It goes outside the scope of the question and hence wouldn't want to comment on this thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as my knowledge about maven goes, it is a standard layout and you cannot customize it with the standard maven plugins out of the box.

Maven switched to a 'default' repository layout with maven2 while maven used to deploy artifacts in a 'legacy' layout with its older version. These two are the only layouts supported out of the box

[maven-deploy-plugin legacy layout](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/examples/deploying-in-legacy-layout.html)

[Details about difference in legacy and default layout](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVENOLD/Repository+Layout+-+Final)

So you cannot use the standard maven plugin for what you want. Having said that, theoretically you should be able to achieve that by implementing ArtifactRepositoryLayout interface. I found some information on this link: https://kthoms.wordpress.com/2009/10/13/how-to-register-a-custom-maven-repository-layout/

Comment: Thanks for the help Ritesh. You seem to have pointed me in the right direction. However, considering the complexity of implementing a non-standard solution, I'd hesitate to go down this route. Thanks once again, nevertheless!